# SpringMVC Interceptor cannot handle slashes

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc, interceptor

In the springmvc, when i send this url to spring interceptor, it does not work.

```
http://localhost/RRAdmin/cgr/cagri.jpg
```

But when use this url, interceptor works.

```
http://localhost/RRAdmin/cgr&cagri.jpg
```

You will see interceptor mapping below

```
<mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**.jpg" />
        <mvc:mapping path="/**.png" />
        <bean class="com.RRAdmin.interceptor.ImageInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

And you'll see my prehandle method below

```
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    File image = new File(uri);
    if(image.exists()) sendFile(image, response.getOutputStream());
    return false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is your web.xml url mapping?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to add a new mapping path like this:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/**/*.jpg" />
<mvc:mapping path="/**/**.png" />
```

Hope it helps.